# In PHP use symbols directly or HTML codes?

Tags: php, html, utf-8, symbols

I'd like to know what's is more correct in PHP using UTF-8 encode.

For example the "copyright symbol", should I use in the code:

```
&copy;
```

Or should I use directly:

```
©
```

What's the more recommended?

Comment: When outputting content to the client side, it's the same as HTML so I would use &copy;

Comment: depends on your output target. if you're not going for a html-rendered view, then entities aren't of much use. on the other hand, entities are more likely to survive charset transitions than the raw naked char is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the encoding of your PHP source files. If they are encoded in UTF-8 you will not have any problem with `©`, If your source files are in ASCII encoding you must use `&copy;`

Comment: I always use UTF-8 so I can always use symbols instead of codes?

Comment: @RedCurley yes - e.g. look for `©` in the source of this (UTF-8) page. Or `☃`

Comment: @RedCurley: Yes, as long as that symbol is supported by UTF-8 and your PHP files is als encode with UTF-8

Comment: Encoding PHP scripts in UTF-8 can be a real bear in a team with multiple programmers. Someone will inevitably open the files in an editor with the penchant of sticking Unicode BOM at the beginning. Or worse, the editor would see the absence of a BOM as evidence of Windows-1252 and proceed to corrupt all non-ASCII characters. I don't know how many hours I've lost fixing these sort of things.

Answer (score -1):

If you use HTML you don't have to care much about encoding, although in PHP you should always use UTF-8.

HTML will work with any encoding.

Comment: It's very frequent for developers to have probl?ms with none-ascii characters - it's misleading to say "HTML will work with any encoding.", It is true, but is only problem free if the source files, the charset header, the database connection, and the db tables are all the same encoding - That's a far stretch from "don't have to care much about encoding"